# Problem with Ultimate Thread Group in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

This is what I expect:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKM7.png)

and this is what I get:
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3myJ.png)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I created separate project with dummy sampler and I've got the following [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbHPm.png)!?
Test was run from cmd with the following command:

```
jmeter -n -t "C:\jmeter\_proj\DummyTest.jmx" -l "C:\jmeter\_proj\UltDummyTest01.jtl" -j "C:\jmeter\_proj\UltDummyTest01.log" -Jdatafile=data/Users1000.csv -DTHREADSADD=200 -DSTARTUP=10 -DSHUTDOWN=10 -DD1=0 -DD2=100 -DD3=200 -DD4=300 -DD5=400 -DH5=200 -DH4=400 -DH3=600 -DH2=800 -DH1=1000
```

Here is the solution on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fH2L5E3eYyQSJU0m8o-5nMTs4ENL9FfI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the complete [solution with data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BK_UplK1eSNUXrEIg4rw8MFejWd6OyM-/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate Thread Group should be precise enough, there should be other factors which shorten ramp-up time and overall test duration and your two partial screenshots don't tell the full story.

1. Make sure to [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode), 1000 threads is way too much for the GUI-based test execution
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. If you're using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) check its settings
4. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

In case of problems update your question with jmeter.log file and schematic view of your test plan (Tools -> Generate Schematic View)

Comment: I updated the question with more info!